# How should we handle questions where we think the OP might be a car jacker?

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/19437/mg-rover-immobiliser-removal), the OP wants to bypass their car security system.

We have no way of telling whether they are the actual owner or not.

How should we handle such questions?

Comment: Not to be pedantic, but a car jacker would have no need for bypassing the security system of a car. A car jacker is someone who steals an occupied vehicle by force or threat, they would simply force the driver to disable the security system.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't have a problem answering these questions or having them on the site. The information is available in the service manual, and most of the time takes special tools, sometimes dealer specific tools to work on these system. Most all of the systems have some sort of time delay so that the procedure is never fast. Most thieves aren't going to wait around for the 10 minute wait that Ford requires for access to the security module even with a Ford dealer scan tool.

I recently had to replace the BCM on an older dodge caravan, the replacement (recycled) BCM was for a vehicle with a security system, the car it was going in was not. There was not an option to reprogram the recycled BCM, once the security module is turned on it cannot be turned off. I simply added the required wiring and drivers door switch to allow the owner to disarm the security system.

Again I don't have a problem with these type of questions being asked and answered here.

Comment: I do not think we should speculate about a users intentions. It's not really our job to judge or police other users actions outside of the forum.

Comment: I think we owe it to the society! not sharing such information.. If its helpful well and good but what if the person reading has bad intentions, we are creating issues for the police and as a good citizen i feel we should try not to give the police a job. At least if we can avoid it.

Comment: But what qualifies us to judge someone's intentions based on a few sentences they wrote on a website? There is a lot of knowledge about stealing cars "in the wild". I think it's *very* unlikely that a Stack Exchange site is the first place someone would go to learn to steal cars.

Comment: @Anarach You can use a brick to build a hospital, or use it to throw it through a window and steal stuff. The brick isn't bad, and they shouldn't stop making bricks because someone might use it to cause harm. Information is not the problem, and this information in particular is easy to access by anyone who half way wants too. It's in the factory service manual it's not a secret

Comment: @Anarach - I agree with David and Larry here. It really isn't our job. What we should be worrying about is getting *good* information out and helping this site succeed. People who would be robbers can find the information out there if they want it. We really aren't helping them do anything. We are helping people who actually need help with their cars, IMHO.

Answer (score 12):

I'm also a programmer and spend some time around other parts of Stack Exchange. I'd to bring some outside insight to this question.

Is there a legitimate (legal) use of this knowledge? If so, I think it should be allowed. In the software world, there are a lot of gray areas where an answer to a question could be used for nefarious purposes. However, that same answer could help someone to make a system more secure, or simply work around a real problem that they need to hack around (jerry-rig). We have no idea what a poster's intentions are. Unless there is no legitimate use for a piece of knowledge, or we're ***entirely*** certain OP is up to something illegal, there's no reason to close the question.

That said, if you don't feel comfortable sharing knowledge with someone because you're afraid of what they'll do with it, ***then don't***. No one is under any obligation to answer any question ever. Please don't ever put yourself in a situation where you would feel guilty for answering someone's question for <s>fake</s> imaginary internet points.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say not to give any details on how to do so - even if the OP is legit, other people reading the page might not be...

Refer them to their local dealer?

Perhaps we should have a specific rule in the site - "Questions about bypassing security systems are off-topic as they could be used for illegal means"

Comment: Good suggestions

Comment: +1 for  other people reading the page might not be legit

Answer (score 2):

They have a 2003 Rover Streetwise, I can assure you they are not trying to steal it!

However, I agree that whatever answers we post on here could be viewed by anyone for all of time so it's worth considering this.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered the question referring them to the dealer, as they can order a key and lock set in for the car, and also program the key.

I have also referred them to the Rover Owners club for more info, as generally enthusiasts have a higher chance of having dealership tools.

Comment: I saw that but Rover went bust in 2005 and there are no longer any dealerships for the vehicle in question.